# Google Tag Manager tag containers

Tags: google-tag-manager

How can I check which tags are being fired through Google tag manager? Especially **Facebook**. Can't see it on Tag assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager has a preview mode, so if you are owner or editor of the container in question you can just "preview" in the upper left. You must allow  third party cookies in the browser.

In the browser where you have enabled the preview mode, there will be a display of debug information shown under the page (if there is not, or it's white without any visible content, then usually third party cookies are not allowed, some content security policy blocks the preview iframe, or some page CSS interferes with the display of the iframe).

If you are not the owner/editor you can use a third party extension like Ghostery (not affiliated), or go the old fashioned route and look in the network tab of your browsers development console (in that case you must have a good idea what http requests to look for, so that is not an end user friendly option).

Answer (score 0):

Enter preview mode within GTM, this can be done via the interface on GTM in the top right hand corner:

[image: GTM Preview Button]

- Once this is activated go to the website the GTM container is
  deployed on.
- Do necessary trigger actions on the site and you should see a summary
  of all tags fired and a breakdown of tags fired on specific events:

[image: GTM Debug Preview]

Now just keep an eye out for your facebook tag within the "Tags Fired On This Page" section. If it is not showing there when it should be, then check your GTM trigger is firing appropriately.